# What does 'lw' instruction with 3 args translate to?

Tags: mips

Normally I see 'lw' double used with 2 args, the destination register and the memory location to load from:

```
lw $2, 3($1)
```

In a CPU implementation the $2 part is the write address sent to the register file and the 3($1) is calculated by the ALU and then passed to memory.  How does work when 'lw' has 3 args as follows:

```
array:
.word 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
lw    $r2, $r24, array
```

Comment: That's probably just an alternative way of writing `lw $r2,array($r24)`

Comment: How does that translate to binary tho??

Comment: Assuming that my guess is correct, it would translate exactly as `lw $r2,array($r24)`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe array here is a label, which will be translated into the immediate field of the lw instruction by the loader, so at load time it might look like this:

> lw $r2, 121($r24)

where 121 will be related to the location in memory where the loader placed the initialized array.